# django rest framework abstract class serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, abstract-class

I have some models like these:

```
class TypeBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class PersonType(TypeBase):
    pass

class CompanyType(TypeBase):
    pass
```

Having this, I want to create just one serializer that holds all these field types (serialization, deserialization, update and save).

To be more specific, I want only one serializer (TypeBaseSerializer) that print the Dropdown on the UI, serialize the json response, deserialize it on post and save it for all my based types.

Something like this:

```
class TypeBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TypeBase
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Is it possible?

Comment: This discussion also useful on subclassing serializers: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1926

Answer (score 21):

I think the following approach is more cleaner. You can set "abstract" field to true for the base serializer and add your common logic for all child serializers.

```
class TypeBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TypeBase
        fields = ('id', 'name')
        abstract = True

    def func(...):
    # ... some logic
```

And then create child serializers and use them for data manipulation.

```
class PersonTypeSerializer(TypeBaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonType
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class CompanyTypeSerializer(TypeBaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyType
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Now you can use the both of these serializers normally for every model.

But if you really want to have one serializers for both the models, then create a container model and a serializer for him too. That is much cleaner :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it gave me a hit to figure out a problem I had.

Comment: Setting `abstract = True` on the `TypeBaseSerializer` because there is no such thing as a abstract serializer. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @GunnerFan you are correct, `abstract` is not a settable attribute.  The proper way to do this is by just using a serializer.Serializer for the base class, which really will end up be a mixin, and a serializers.ModelSerializer as the derived class

Answer (score 20):

As already mentioned in [Sebastian Wozny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33137535/3446669), you can't use a ModelSerializer with an abstract base model.

Also, there is nothing such as an abstract Serializer, as some other answers have suggested. So setting `abstract = True` on the Meta class of a serializer **will not work**.

However you need not use use a `ModelSerializer` as your base/parent serializer. You can use a `Serializer` and then take advantage of Django's multiple inheritance. Here is how it works:

```
class TypeBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # Need to re-declare fields since this is not a ModelSerializer
    name = serializers.CharField()
    id = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    def someFunction(self):
        #... will be available on child classes ...
        pass

class PersonTypeSerializer(TypeBaseSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PersonType
        fields = TypeBaseSerializer.Meta.fields + ['another_field']


class CompanyTypeSerializer(TypeBaseSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyType
        fields = TypeBaseSerializer.Meta.fields + ['some_other_field']
```

So now since the fields `name` and `id` are declared on the parent class (TypeBaseSerializer), they will be available on `PersonTypeSerializer` and since this is a child class of `ModelSerializer` those fields will be populated from the model instance.

You can also use `SerializerMethodField` on the `TypeBaseSerializer`, even though it is not a ModelSerializer.

```
class TypeBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # you will have to re-declare fields here since this is not a ModelSerializer
    name = serializers.CharField()
    id = serializers.CharField()
    other_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'other_field']

    def get_other_field(self, instance):
        # will be available on child classes, which are children of ModelSerializers
        return instance.other_field
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a major headache and your solution worked

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the approved answer.  It solved my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 17):

You [can't use](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L903) a `ModelSerializer` with an abstract base model.
From restframework.serializers:

```
if model_meta.is_abstract_model(self.Meta.model):
        raise ValueError(
            'Cannot use ModelSerializer with Abstract Models.'
        )
```

I wrote a serializer_factory function for a similar problem:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from restframework.serializers import ModelSerializer
def serializer_factory(mdl, fields=None, **kwargss):
""" Generalized serializer factory to increase DRYness of code.

:param mdl: The model class that should be instanciated
:param fields: the fields that should be exclusively present on the serializer
:param kwargss: optional additional field specifications
:return: An awesome serializer
"""

    def _get_declared_fields(attrs):
        fields = [(field_name, attrs.pop(field_name))
                  for field_name, obj in list(attrs.items())
                  if isinstance(obj, Field)]
        fields.sort(key=lambda x: x[1]._creation_counter)
        return OrderedDict(fields)

    # Create an object that will look like a base serializer
    class Base(object):
        pass

    Base._declared_fields = _get_declared_fields(kwargss)

    class MySerializer(Base, ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = mdl

        if fields:
            setattr(Meta, "fields", fields)

    return MySerializer
```

You can then use the factory to produce serializers as needed:

```
def typebase_serializer_factory(mdl):
    myserializer = serializer_factory(
        mdl,fields=["id","name"],
        #owner=HiddenField(default=CurrentUserDefault()),#Optional additional configuration for subclasses 
      )
    return myserializer
```

Now instanciate different subclass serializers:

```
persontypeserializer = typebase_serializer_factory(PersonType)
companytypeserializer = typebase_serializer_factory(CompanyType)
```

Comment: This solution seems to work for my problem, but is there any way to be less generic? I think in my case, i'll always know the fields of my types and i just need to instanciate it dynamically.

Comment: You could create two serializers for the subclasses. I was in a situation with 7 subclasses and different serializer modes, so being generic was crucial.

Comment: Where is the `Field` variable coming from in the `_get_declared_fields` function

Answer (score 9):

Just iterating a bit over @adki's answer:

1. it is possible to skip model for TypeBaseSerializer;
2. derived serializers can refer to TypeBaseSerializer.Meta, so you would change them in a single place.

> ```
> class TypeBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
>     class Meta:
>         fields = ('id', 'name', 'created')
>         abstract = True
>
>     def func(...):
>     # ... some logic
>
> class PersonTypeSerializer(TypeBaseSerializer):
>     class Meta:
>         model = PersonType
>         fields = TypeBaseSerializer.Meta.fields + ('age', 'date_of_birth')
>
> class CompanyTypeSerializer(TypeBaseSerializer):
>     class Meta:
>         model = CompanyType
>         fields = TypeBaseSerializer.Meta.fields
> ```

Comment: As far as I see the class `serializers.Serializer` has no attribute `meta`. It has however an attribute `Meta`. So I suppose it should be rather `TypeBaseSerializer.Meta.fields` instead of `TypeBaseSerializer.meta.fields`.

Comment: You have set a `model = ..` attribute on `PersonTypeSerializer.Meta`. However `PersonTypeSerializer` is a child class of `serializers.Serializer`, so I don't think the model attribute will work there.