# Return literal JSON instead of __str__ Django Rest Framework

Tags: model, django-rest-framework

Whenever I declare an Abstract Model in Django to allow for nested models Django asks me to declare a **str** as string representation of that Model. The app I am writing is supposed to be an API returning JSON and instead of the actual object Django returns whatever I have defined as **str**.

Example:

My Model:

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
  a = models.CharField()
  b = models.CharField()

  def __str__(self):
    return 'some string'

  class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Parent Model:

```py
class ParentModel(models.Model):
  someModel = models.EmbeddedModelField(
    model_container=SomeModel
  )
```

Serializer:

```py
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = ParentModel
    fields = ('someModel')
```

View:

```py
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = ParentModel.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ParentSerializer
```

Now, when I send an Object of `ParentModel` I would like to send something like this: `{ someModel: { a: 'something', b: 'something else' } }` and not whatever is defined in `__str__`.
I understand, that I could define the `__str__` method to return all its fields as a string and then put the curly brackets around the output as strings as well, but there must be a better way to do this?

Comment: add your `view` and `serializer`

Answer (score 0):

As `SomeModel` is an abstract model, DRF do not allow you to create a serializer for that model. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33137535/4665915), where a custom serializer for an abstract model is created.

If `SomeModel` class was not abstract you would need to create a serializer for your `SomeModel` class and use that in your `ParentSerializer` class as writable nested serializer. So roughly, you need to implement something like this:

```py
# serializers.py
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('some_fields')

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    someModel = SomeModelSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = ParentModel
        fields = ('someModel')
```

You can find more details about writable nested serializers from [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers).

Comment: I have tried this before and django took issue with trying to write a serializer for a model that is declared `abstract`, is there a quick workaround for that too?

Comment: I haven't noticed that SomeModel was abstract. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code as below

```
class ParentModel(models.Model):
  someModel = models.EmbeddedModelField(
    model_container=SomeModel
  )

  def __str__(self):
      return "{}".format(self.someModel)
```

Comment: The error is not thrown because the `ParentModel` needs to have a `__str__` function but the `SomeModel` needs a String representation.

Comment: update info like how you are sending request and what you are getting response