# Serialize Model from Derived (Abstract) Model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following models:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ....
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BillingAddress(Address):
    is_default = models.BooleanField()
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'billing_address'
```

I'm trying to build a serializer for BillingAddress:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        model = AddressModel

class BillingAddressSerializer(AddressSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return AddressSerializer(obj, context=self.context).to_representation(obj)

    class Meta(AddressSerializer.Meta):
        model = UserBillingAddress
        fields = (
            'id',
            'is_default',
        )
```

I keep getting:

```
 ValueError: Cannot use ModelSerializer with Abstract Models.
```

How can I build my BillingAddressSerializer to reflect both classes?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe try to put `abstract = False` in `BillingAddressSerializer`'s `Meta`class?

Comment: Similar query and it's resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137165/django-rest-framework-abstract-class-serializer

Answer (score 1):

An abstract model is a base class in which you define fields you want to include in all child models. Django doesn't create any database table for abstract models. A database table is created for each child model, including the fields inherited from the abstract class and the ones defined in the child model.

Since there is no "Address" table, so "AddressSerializer" would be invalid.