# Django nested document serializer problem

Tags: json, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, djongo

i want to store json files in mongodb, create and get with django rest framework.

i share my code below. this code insert posted data into mongo.
but when i 'get'  data, nested object represent as string.

i create nested model's serializer and define in Root serializer but i get error "Cannot use ModelSerializer with Abstract Models."

i want to get object as json: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpdw9.png)

i researched a lot but i haven't found anything about this.

```py
    ###########################models.py########################

    from djongo import models

    class Nest(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
        icon = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    class Root(models.Model):
        #_id = models.ObjectIdField()
        country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
        country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
        nested = models.EmbeddedField(
            model_container=Nest, null=True)
            
    ###########################serializers.py#####################
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import Root

    class RootSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Root
            fields = '__all__'
            
    ###########################views.py###########################
    from django.shortcuts import render

    from django.http.response import JsonResponse
    from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
    from rest_framework import status

    from .models Root
    from .serializers import RootSerializer
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

    @api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
    def root(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            first_root = Root.objects.first()
            root_serializer = RootSerializer(first_root, many=False)
            return JsonResponse(root_serializer.data, safe=False)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            root_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            root_serializer = RootSerializer(data=root_data)
            if root_serializer.is_valid():
                root_serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(root_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return JsonResponse(root_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    ###########################urls.py###########################
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from rootApp import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^api/root$', views.root),
    ]

    #settings.py
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'root_db',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': 27017,
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718995/serialize-model-from-derived-abstract-model

Answer (score 0):

i mantioned in my question, my problem is nested document represent to client by abstract model which is not serializable.

in this manner if i want to serialize nested document i don't make abstact model but in this point i also don't want create database collection for this nested document model thus i typed this models as abstract.

so i create nested models as abstract until migrate and create database collection correspond  'root' model.

after that i change nested documents model to normal model.this i don't migrate after this changes.

in this manner code work what i expected as.

i think if i must do migrate again i change nested documents to abstract and i will perform migrate. after migrate i will change again this abstract model to normal model.

maybe everybody know this  or maybe there is more elagant solution about this. i solved my problem i hope this helps to somebody

SOLUTION in Code#####

###########################models.py########################

```
from djongo import models

isMigrate = False       //added this line

class Nest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = isMigrate        //changed this line. 

class Root(models.Model):
    #_id = models.ObjectIdField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)
    nested = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Nest, null=True)
        
###########################serializers.py#####################
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Root

class NestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):              # added
    class Meta:                                                 # this
        model = Nest                                            #
        fields = '__all__'                                      # lines

class RootSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Root
        fields = '__all__'
```

solution : whenever you migrate($python manage.py migrate) you change 'isMigrate' variable is 'True', otherwise this variable should be 'False'. this is importent because when we perform migrate we just want create 'migration file' after this migration file created this variable can be 'False'. in operational situations this variable also should be 'False'.