# I want to list all elements from abstract class Product and its categories (Smartphones, Tv ) etc

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, model, xmlserializer

```py
class ProductSerizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Category.objects)
    title_of_product = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(required=True)
    image_of_product = serializers.ImageField(required=True)
    description_of_product = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    price_of_product = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, required=True)
    

class Product(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name="category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=225,verbose_name="Title",null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image_of_product = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Image", null=True)
    description_of_product = models.TextField(verbose_name = "Descripwtion", null = True)
    price_of_product = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2, verbose_name="Price", null=True)
```

and I want to list all elements from categories, but I cannot serialize this class. How should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137165/django-rest-framework-abstract-class-serializer), which talks about `abtract` models and how to serialize them