# I need to create a serializer that takes fields that are not in the model, yet they are in the common model linked with a foreign key

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need to create a serializer that takes fields that are not in the model, yet they are in the common model linked with a foreign key. I already wrote the logic to create instances yet django keeps saying that the field I am passing does not exist in the model to which the serializer belongs.

```
serializers.py
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    isApproved = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="user_id.is_staff")
    date = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ['id', 'user_id', 'name', 'description', 'image', 'isApproved', 'tag', 'date']


class _ContentSerializer(ContentSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(default=serializers.DateTimeField())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        content_data = {}
        for field in super().fields:
            content_data[field] = validated_data.pop(field)
        content = Content.objects.create(**content_data)
        instance = self.Meta.model.objects.create(content_id=content, **validated_data)
        return instance

 
class EventSerializer(_ContentSerializer):
    location = serializers.URLField()

    class Meta(_ContentSerializer.Meta):
        model = Event
        fields = _ContentSerializer.Meta.fields + ['location']



models.py
class Content(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='.images/cover_pages/', null=True, blank=True)
    tag = models.TextField(max_length=20, null=True)
    isApproved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)



    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name} - {self.isApproved}'
    

class _Content(models.Model):
    content_id = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.content_id}'
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    

class Event(_Content):
    location = models.URLField()
```

I need to create serializer for event that will take content fields as well in order to create its instance and then bind it to event's instance
I tried to ask GPT yet it seems that it is useless now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django rest framework abstract class serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137165/django-rest-framework-abstract-class-serializer)